# Class template where variable class derives from certain abstract class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, abstract-class

I want to ensure that in the definition of the following templated class B, that the class A derives from an abstract class C. Can I do this?

```
template <class A>
class B {
    // A must derive from C
    ...
};
```

I am using C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::is_base_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_base_of):

```
template <class A>
class B {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<C, A>::value
                  , "A must derive from C");
    //...
};
```

Note that `is_base_of<C, C>::value` is true, so you may want to also use [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to ensure `A` is not actually `C` itself:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<C, A>::value && !std::is_same<C, A>::value
              , "A must derive from C");
```

Comment: When the type is not an inheritable type (That is, is not a class/struct), `std::is_base_of` returns false? Or it has an internal assert? The question is: OP have to ensure that A is a class?

Comment: @Manu343726 There are no restrictions on the types of C or A, it just does "the right thing". Quoting cppreference.com: *If Derived is derived from Base or if both are the same non-union class, provides the member constant value equal to true. Otherwise value is false.*

Answer (score 0):

Overall this is a [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) problem.

In C++11 there are better ways, but if you're using C++03, you could try something like this:

```
template <class A>
class B {
public:
    B() { dummy((A*)0); }

private:
    void dummy(C *test) {}
};
```

That is, add dummy function taking a pointer of type `C`. Then call it from your constructor(s) with a value of type `A*`. This cannot compile for types where `A` doesn't derive from `C`.

Comment: I am using C++11. I should have said that.